# Deserialize JSON array of one-attribute objects to a collection of strings

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm still learning Newtonsoft.Json and I was wondering if there a nice way to deserialize JSON array (*ListField*) that contain one-attribute items directly to a collection of strings?

```
{
    "FieldString":"string field",
    "FieldBool":false,
    "FieldId":"2513d3e3-3e1d-409d-b5a0-58eaa7cd6da9",
    "ListField":[
        {
            "Name":"string field 1"
        },
        {
            "Name":"string field 2"
        },
    ]
}
```

```
public class ClassName
{
    public string FieldString;
    public bool FieldBool;
    public Guid FieldId;
    public ICollection<string> ListField;
}
```

I deserialize most of the JSON strings using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassName>(jsonString);`. But to do that here I would need to create an additional class with just *Name* string attribute like the one below and use `public ICollection<ListFieldItem> ListField;` instead of a string.

```
public class ListFieldItem
{
    public string Name;
}
```

I really want to avoid having a class with a single attribute if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on @[weichch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10620317/weichch)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60753304/10263), if you wanted to solve this using a custom `JsonConverter`, here is what the code might look like for that:

```
public class ListOfNamesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ICollection<string>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JArray.Load(reader)
                     .Children<JObject>()
                     .Select(jo => (string)jo["Name"])
                     .ToList();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, mark your `ListField` member with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute like this:

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ListOfNamesConverter))]
    public ICollection<string> ListField;
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0VtxDo

Answer (score 4):

You could use one of the following:

- JSON [converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeClass.htm) for `ListField` property
- A dedicated constructor marked as `JsonConstructor` [attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConstructorAttribute.htm)

Example:

```
public class ClassName
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    private ClassName(List<IDictionary> listField)
    {
        ListField = listField.Select(x => x["Name"].ToString()).ToArray();
    }

    public string FieldString;
    public bool FieldBool;
    public Guid FieldId;
    public ICollection<string> ListField;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I really want to avoid having a class with a single attribute if possible.

it is possible to do as @weichch said

however look at the json.

```
    "ListField":[
        {
            "Name":"string field 1"
        },
        {
            "Name":"string field 2"
        },
    ]
```

It contains list of objects in the `ListField`. Right now `ListFieldItem` has the only one `Name` property.
In the next API version you may get `ListFieldItem` type extended with additional properties, like `Weight`, `BirthDate`, whatever.

So you will have to do strong source code modifications to move to the next API version.

You can create the `ListFieldItem` despite it is boring or takes extra space ;) in your project.

Additionally (if you are interesting in the Name list only) you can provide `ClassName` extension that will extract the `ListFieldItem.Name` values to the `IEnumerable<string>` like

```cs
public static class ClassNameExt
{
 public IEnumerable<string> GetItemNames(this ClassName value)
 {
  return value.ListField.Select(_ => _.Name);
 }
}
```

This will give you clear `ClassName` and `ListFieldItem` types that can be easily adjusted (by you or another dev in your team) with next API version.